# Overwrite or reset widget style in GTK3

Tags: widget, gtk, vte

I use the `gnome-terminal` which uses the `vte` library, which in turn provides the `VteTerminal` widget. Using an appropriate `gtk.css` file, I have added a padding around the `VteTerminal` widget.

I embed the `VteTerminal` in a seperate GTK3 application, which inherits the style configured in my `gtk.css`.

How do I prevent the `VteTerminal` widget or any other widget from using any style provider, or alternatively, how do I reset their styles?

Comment: Maybe you can use `gtk_widget_get_style_context ()` and remove the classes in the style context.

Comment: @elya5 Sadly, `gtk_style_context_list_classes` gives me an empty list, so there is nothing to be removed.